# Generate template in Jinja2 from output in ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

This is my question: need to take from the csv file data and from this data run one command and present in a jinja2 template the result. The problem is that everytime that I run the playbook, this override my jinja2 template. Does anyone know how to not override this?

```
name: check vrf configuration 
  hosts: HOST1
  gather_facts: no

  tasks: 
    - name: Read
      read_csv:
        path: /ansible/data-vlan.csv
      register: csvfile_out

    - name: Configuring
      include: vrf.yml file={item}  
      with_items: "{{ csvfile_out.list }}"
```

data-vlan.csv

```
VRF
CUSTOMER1,
CUSTOMER2,
```

vrf.yml

```
 - name: Extract Data
      set_fact:
        VRF: "{{ lookup('csvfile', '{{item.VRF}} file=data-vlan.csv col=0 delimiter=,') }}"
    
    - name: show VRF 
      ios_command:
        commands: 
         - show run vrf {{VRF}}
    - name: jinja2
      template:
        src: template.j2
        dest: /ansible/VRF_STATUS.txt
```

template.j2

```
{% for item in status.stdout_lines.0 %}
{% if 'interface' in item %}
no interface {{ item.split().1 }}
{% elif 'vrf context' in item %}
no {{ item }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor%}
```

output:

```
],
"stdout_lines": [
    [
        "!Command: show running-config vrf CUSTOMER1",
        "!Running configuration last done at: Fri Feb 18 11:35:21 2022",
        "!Time: Mon Feb 28 11:37:51 2022",
        "",
        "version 7.0(3)I7(8) Bios:version 07.66 ",
        "",
        "interface Vlan10",
        "  vrf member CUSTOMER1",
        "",
        "interface Vlan12",
        "  vrf member CUSTOMER1",
        "vrf context CUSTOMER1",
        "  description [CUSTOMER1]",
        "  ip route 0.0.0.0/0 10.1.1.1",
        "  address-family ipv4 unicast"
    ],

],
"stdout_lines": [
    [
        "!Command: show running-config vrf CUSTOMER1",
        "!Running configuration last done at: Fri Feb 18 11:35:21 2022",
        "!Time: Mon Feb 28 11:37:51 2022",
        "",
        "version 7.0(3)I7(8) Bios:version 07.66 ",
        "",
        "interface Vlan20",
        "  vrf member CUSTOMER2",
        "",
        "interface Vlan22",
        "  vrf member CUSTOMER2",
        "vrf context CUSTOMER2",
        "  description [CUSTOMER2]",
        "  ip route 0.0.0.0/0 10.2.2.1",
        "  address-family ipv4 unicast"
    ],
```

VRF_STATUS.txt

```
no interface vlan20
no interface vlan22
no vrf context CUSTOMER2
```

**- Actually would like to have the two customers like that:

```
   no interface vlan10
   no interface vlan12
   no vrf context CUSTOMER1
   no interface vlan20
   no interface vlan22
   no vrf context CUSTOMER2**
```

Any idea? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly, you extract data from a yaml file and want to create a file containing that data that were templated with jinja2.

I suggest to not use the template module, but the blockinfile module combined with a template lookup like so:

```
- name: jinja2
  blockinfile:
    create: true
    block: "{{ lookup('template', 'template.j2') }}"
    path: /ansible/VRF_STATUS.txt
```

this way, the templated values are appended to the file. if you do not configure on how to handle the markers, you will have some "BEGIN" and "END" markers in your file.  see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html for more infos.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion although the result is the same, every time that execute the playbook it  overrides the template and only see the last value taken on the file (CUSTOMER2)